# Access all bound values

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, knockout.js

I have a big project written in ASP.NET I need to modify. It uses knockout.js to bind values:

```
$(document).ready(function () { 
    var model = new MyViewModel();
    ko.applyBindings(model);
});
```

Afterwards, the bindig is done:

```
<span data-bind="text: myText"></span>
```

I now want to access all values that were bound. Unfortunately, I'm not very experienced with those frameworks.

With

```
console.log(model);
```

I get a huge output (extract):

```
MyViewModel{settings: [...]}
TypeSeriesSubscription: c()
barClick: (e, bar)
cancelSetting: ()
chartClick: (value)
chartUser: c()
charts: c()
[...]
```

With

```
model.myText
```

I get just `undifined`.

How can I access `myText` in order to just put its text out in a console?

Comment: if `text` is an observable use `model.text()`, if its a var then use `model.text`. Also place `var model = new MyViewModel();` outside `document.ready` to test in console.

Comment: @Dandy: With `model.myText` I get `undefined` and with `model.myText()` I get `model.myText is not a function`.

Comment: Show the code of **MyViewModel**

Answer (score 0):

You're scoping `model` to only exist inside of the `ready` function. Try this:

```
var model = new MyViewModel();
$(document).ready(function () { 
    ko.applyBindings(model);
});
```

Then you should be able to:

```
console.log(model.myText());
```

Since KO relies on an observable pattern, you need to use `()` after any property to see its current value.